# For loop only showing last element in string array (Xamarin)

Tags: forms, xamarin

Sorry if tgis sounds like a duplicate question, but most responses seem to be for C# Console apps rather than Visual Studio Xamarin mobile apps.

```
namespace ArrayPractice
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string[] StringArray = new string[] { "Apple", "Baker", "Caramel", "Danish" };

            int deli = StringArray.Length;
       
           for (int i = 0; i < deli; i++)
                {
                    DeliNames.Text = StringArray[i]; 
    //DeliNames is x:Name assigned to XAML Label } } } }
                }
            }
        }
    
}
```

Shouldn't the following code return all the elements in the string  array on a separate line, not just the last one. The DisplayAlert is giving me an initial value of 3. then decreasing by 1 when I click OK and finally shows the "Danish"

Comment: Try `DeliNames.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, StringArray);` and remove the loop altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Currently on each iteration you are assigning the array value to your Text property, you could concatenate it with `+=`, or you could use a `StringBuilder` or `Span`, there are multiple ways.:

```
// Environment.NewLine for newline
DeliNames.Text += StringArray[i] + Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: Use `Environment.NewLine` rather than `"\n"`. Windows uses `"\r\n"` and Linux `"\n"`. Using `Environment.NewLine` correctly sets it for you.

Comment: Adding the +=  and the Environment. NewLine did the magic I was looking for.  Thanks for the tips!

Comment: @Brent_H Great. You can show your appreciation by marking this as the accepted answer :)